# Every key is getting updated instead of only one in hash table

Tags: java, arraylist

In the starting hashtable contains key(String) and value(ArrayList). After running the below code for a particular amount of time, in every updation every key is getting updated with same ArrayList. Here is the code:

```
                    int c=0;
                    ke=location.keys();
                    value=new ArrayList<String>();
                    System.out.println("Before operation: "+value.size());
                    while(ke.hasMoreElements() && c==0)
                    {
                        //System.out.println("Start  value Size: "+value.size());
                        String hKey=ke.nextElement();
                        String spl[]=hKey.split(", ");
                        Double kLat=Double.parseDouble(spl[0]);
                        Double kLon=Double.parseDouble(spl[1]);
                        if(haversine(lat, lon, kLat, kLon)<=30)
                        {
                            count++;
                            c=1;
                            value.clear();
                            value=location.get(hKey);
                            location.remove(hKey);
                            value.add(lat+", "+lon);
                            if(spl.length==2)
                            {
                                ky++;
                                hKey=hKey+", "+timedate;
                            }
                            else
                                hKey=kLat+", "+kLon+", "+timedate;
                            location.put(hKey, value);
                            System.out.println();
                            break;
                        }
                     }
```

Comment: You do indeed have just one list: the one you allocate before the loop. You need to replace `value.clear()` with `value = new ArrayList()`. Oh, and value is not used outside the loop.

Comment: I tried that too, but same result.Every key is getting updated with same value.

Comment: How do you create the location map, does the map share the same List instance for all keys or not?

Comment: In the beginning location hashtable contains centroids as key and empty arrayList as value.